# Integrate the function $f(x, y, z)=\sqrt{3x^2 + 3y^2 + z + 1}$ over the surface given by...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, integration

Integrate the function $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{3x^2 + 3y^2 + z + 1}$ over the surface given by the graph of $z = g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ over the region $1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$

Comment: You likely got the downvote because you did not give us any insight about what you have done and what you are looking for.  I have provided a solution despite this, but in the future, please provide what you have done so we may best answer your question.

Comment: As @RonGordon has suggested, please provide some insight into the problem or atleast provide what you are looking for or what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function being integrated over the surface is really just a simple function of $z$:

$$3 x^2+3 y^2+z+1 = 4 z+1$$

Also, the surface integral is given by

$$\int_1^4 dz \,2 \pi r(z)\, \sqrt{1+\left ( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right )^2}\, \sqrt{4 z+1} $$

Given that $z=r^2$ then $r(z) = \sqrt{z}$.  Then the integral is

$$2 \pi \int_1^4 dz \, \sqrt{z} \, \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4 z}} \, \sqrt{4 z+1} = 4 \pi \int_1^4 dz \, \left (z+\frac14\right)$$

The reader should be able to verify that the integral has a value of $33 \pi$.